# What would make a good PHP validaton class?

Tags: php, html

I would like to read about your opinions on what the best way to create a validation class is. 
Below i pasted in my version, it's not really extensive yet, but is it the right approach so far?

I want every element which could appear in a form and which should be validated to have its own properties, in terms of string length for strings or file size for images or files in general (see below).

Also, is it better to declare these rules as nested arrays or should I put them in one big string, which would then be split up during the process?

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

class Phrase {
    //creates parts of sentences, not important
    static function additive(array $limbs) {
        return implode(' and ', array_filter([implode(', ', array_slice($limbs, 0, -1)), end($limbs)], 'strlen'));
    }
}

class Text {
    static function validate($item) {
        $err = array();
        $value = $_POST[$item] ?? $_GET[$item];
        $criteria = FormProcess::$criteria[$item];
        foreach($criteria as $critKey => $critVal) {
            if($critKey === 'required' && empty($value)) {
                $err[] = "is required";
            } else if(!empty($value)) {
                switch($critKey) {
                    case 'length':
                        if(is_array($critVal)) {
                            //min and max set
                            if(mb_strlen($value) < $critVal[0] || mb_strlen($value) > $critVal[1]) {
                                $this->err[] = "must contain between {$critVal[0]} and {$critVal[1]} characters"; 
                            }
                        } else {
                            //max set only
                            if(mb_strlen($value) > $critVal) {
                                $err[] = "must contain a maximum of $critVal characters";
                            }
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'pattern':
                        if(!preg_match($critVal[0], $value)) {
                            $err[] = "may consist of {$critVal[1]} only";
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'function':
                        $result = static::$critVal($value);
                        if($result) {
                            $err[] = $result;
                        }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(!empty($err)) {
            return "{$criteria['name']} " . Phrase::additive($err) . "!";
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static function email($email) {
        //checks if given string is a valid email address
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return "is invalid";
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class File {
    //checks for aspects like filesize...
    static function validate() {
        //...
    }   
}

class Image extends File {
    static function validate() {
        parent::validate(); //perform general file checks first
        //...checks for images specifically
    }
}

class Video extends File {
    static function validate() {
        parent::validate(); //perform general file checks first
        //...checks for videos specifically
    }
}

class FormProcess {
    public $errors;

    //declare, what kind of requirements the items must meet
    static $criteria = array(
        'email' => array(
            'type'     => 'Text',
            'required' => true,
            'name'     => 'Email',
            'length'   => 48,
            'function' => 'email', 
        ),

        'username' => array(
            'type'     => 'Text',
            'required' => true,
            'name'     => 'Username',
            'length'   => [4, 24],
            'pattern'  => ['/^[-\w]+$/', "alphanumeric characters, underscores and hyphens"],
        ),

        'password' => array(
            'type'     => 'Text',
            'required' => true,
            'name'     => 'Password',
            'length'   => [6, 100],
            'pattern'  => ['/^[\S]+$/', "non-whitespace characters"],
        ),
    );

    //runs the validate function on each item while storing occuring errors
    function __construct(array $items) {
        foreach($items as $item) {
            $class = self::$criteria[$item]['type'];
            $result = $class::validate($item);
            if($result) {
                $this->errors[] = $result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then all you had to do, is, naming all expected items (by their html 'name' attribute in the form) in an array and pass it through the constructor, which would then run the appropriate validation function on each item.

```
$expected = ['username', 'password'];
$signup = new FormProcess($expected);

if($signup->errors) { 
    ?>
    There was something wrong with your request:
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($signup->errors as $error) { ?>
            <li><?= $error ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
```

I hope to learn from mistakes and make improvements to the code from you where they are needed. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

You may want to find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: If you use a json string for the rules, there's no need for you to serialize/deserialize it yourself, since you can rely on json_encode and json_decode. It's also easy to hand-edit.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, they're both very helpful. I will look forward to asking on quora and also fixing the arrays.

Comment: @nooby_web_developer - you're welcome. CodeProject is another place where extended discussions are appropriate. :)